# getting No such file or directory when I try to build chromium

Tags: build, chromium, ninja

I am getting following when I try to build chromium

```
c:\src\chromium\src>ninja -C out\Default2 chrome
ninja: Entering directory `out\Default2'
[6/28555] CXX obj/base/base_static/pe_image.obj
FAILED: obj/base/base_static/pe_image.obj
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Stu
dio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64/cl.exe" /nologo /showIncludes /FC @obj/base/base_static/pe
_image.obj.rsp /c ../../base/win/pe_image.cc /Foobj/base/base_static/pe_image.ob
j /Fd"obj/base/base_static_cc.pdb"
c:\src\chromium\src\base\win\pe_image.cc(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open incl
ude file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory
[7/28555] CXX obj/base/base_paths/base_paths.obj
FAILED: obj/base/base_paths/base_paths.obj
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Stu
dio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64/cl.exe" /nologo /showIncludes /FC @obj/base/base_paths/bas
e_paths.obj.rsp /c ../../base/base_paths.cc /Foobj/base/base_paths/base_paths.ob
j /Fd"obj/base/base_paths_cc.pdb"
c:\src\chromium\src\base\files\file_path.h(105): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory
[8/28555] CXX obj/base/base_paths/base_paths_win.obj
FAILED: obj/base/base_paths/base_paths_win.obj
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Stu
dio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64/cl.exe" /nologo /showIncludes /FC @obj/base/base_paths/bas
e_paths_win.obj.rsp /c ../../base/base_paths_win.cc /Foobj/base/base_paths/base_
paths_win.obj /Fd"obj/base/base_paths_cc.pdb"
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um\winnt.h(34): fata
l error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory
[11/28555] ACTION //base:build_date(//build/toolchain/win:x64)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This is my first time building chroium,
I have visual studio 2015 community edition installed with Windows SDK , and also installed WDK seperately without which "gn gen out/Default2" was not working

Any idea what this issue could be

Answer (score 1):

1.Your build errors:

```
c:\src\chromium\src\base\win\pe_image.cc(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory 
c:\src\chromium\src\base\files\file_path.h(105): fatal error C1083: Cannot openinclude file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory  
c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\um\winnt.h(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory
```

2.You may need to check the header files which caused the build errors:

The headers, sources, and libraries are now distributed as part of a separate [Universal CRT SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx).

Excerpt from the above:
Visual C++ SDK. The headers, sources, and libraries are now distributed as part of a separate Universal CRT SDK. This SDK is included with Visual Studio; it is installed by default to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10. The debug ucrtbased.dll is also included as part of this SDK and is installed to the system directory.

3.You can also try to reference the following [links](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx), it's the same issue with yours: